# Odoo - How to track events in tree view

Tags: odoo, odoo-9, odoo-10, odoo-view

Hi i am using Odoo 10e.

I want to add a jquery plugin into tree view. All things are set i added external libraries using templates. Now i just want to know which event is the last event to be executed in `list_view.js` at last. So that i can initialize my plugin there.

My plugin needs a table in the DOM to run and when i try to initialize my plugin in `init` or `load_list` methods of `list_view.js` it doesn't work because at that time DOM is not rendered.

I also tried to add custom event in `list_view.js` `events` method but same here event is not firing.

Comment: You can add your custom code in render_record. This might br thr last one to call

Comment: no it execute way before rendering table